# PUT request from Angular5 to spring-boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, angular5

As You know the put request looks like this :

```
put(url: string, body: any, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response>
```

So in angular for my case it  looks like this :

```
updateIntervention(id:number,idDev:number){
    if(this.authService.getToken()==null) {
      this.authService.loadToken();
    }
    return this.http.put(this.host+"/updateIntervention/"+id,idDev,{headers:new HttpHeaders({'Authorization':this.authService.getToken()})});
  }
```

So in spring-data(back end) , the method waiting for a PUT request should be something like for example:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/updateIntervention/{id}",method = RequestMethod.PUT)
 public Intervention update(@PathVariable Long id , @RequestBody B obj){

 ... 
}
```

So obj here is an object of class B which has an attribte of type Long that will return the body of the PUT request sent by angular5 .

my problem is i keep creating these different classes in spring-data (because somtimes i send only one attribute in body , that's why i create a new class to represent it  ) so i can get the body sent by angular even thought it contains only one attribute , as in this case idDev .

are there any better ways to avoid creating new classes in spring-data so i cant get the idDev send by front end in body ?

If i put only for exemple :

```
public Intervention update(@PathVariable Long id , @RequestBody long idDev){
```

i get error of deserialization etc ..

Any idea or it is not possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Put your param as `form-data` and use `@RequestParam` to get it in your controller:

```
public Intervention update(@PathVariable Long id , @RequestParam long idDev){
```

Comment: Thanks for answring :) , what do you mean by form-data ?

Comment: Yes. Since you only pass a single request param, no need to use RequestBody there

Comment: Ah okey , but wha does form-data mean ? Is it the same way as i did in angular5 put request ?